# If statement should give int and alert when using 0

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For a beginners JS assignment I need to divide numbers between each other and always beginning with the biggest number. So I never get decimal numbers. 
But when the usage of a 0 is involved then the output should give an alert that using a 0 is not allowed.

So I added a second if statement

```
if (nGetal2 == 0 || nGetal1 == 0){
    sResultaat += " 0 niet toegelaten in deze uitvoering";
    console.log(sResultaat);
}
```

But this makes the output again giving decimal numbers. 9 / 3 should be 3 and 3 / 9 should also be 3 because the biggest number is chosen for every dividing.

I thougt if I used a || operand that I could say that either nGetal1 or nGetal2 should never do anything if a 0 is used.

```
<script>
var eKnop = document.querySelector('#deKnop');
eKnop.onclick = bereken;

function bereken() {
    console.log('knop werkt')


var eGetal1 = document.getElementById('getal1');
var eGetal2 = document.getElementById('getal2');

// de getallen

var nGetal1 = parseInt(eGetal1.value);
var nGetal2 = parseInt(eGetal2.value);



var sResultaat = "";

if(nGetal1 > nGetal2) {
    sResultaat = nGetal1 / nGetal2;

}
if (nGetal2 == 0 || nGetal1 == 0){
    sResultaat += " 0 not allowed";

}
else { 
    sResultaat = nGetal2 / nGetal1;
}
console.log(sResultaat);

}

</script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if`/`else` is set up wrong.

You do this first bit of division if `nGetal1 > nGetal2`. *Then*, you check `nGetal2 == 0 || nGetal1 == 0`, and if that's false, you go to the `else`, and do division *again*; overwriting the first division result. I believe you meant:

```
if (nGetal2 == 0 || nGetal1 == 0){
    sResultaat += " 0 not allowed";

} else if (nGetal1 > nGetal2) {  // Only attempt division if neither operand is 0
    sResultaat = nGetal1 / nGetal2;

} else { 
    sResultaat = nGetal2 / nGetal1;
}

console.log(sResultaat);
```

If either operand is 0, both of the division checks are skipped. If they aren't 0, `nGetal1 > nGetal2` is checked. If that check is true, `nGetal1 / nGetal2` is carried out. If it's false, `nGetal2 / nGetal1` is carried out.

Comment: I have a follow-up question about this. What if I do need to divide 0 / 3 that would be an allowed 0.

Comment: I have a follow-up question about this. What if I do need to divide 0 / 3 that would be an allowed 0. @Carcigenicate

Comment: @Sauvage Add a new `if` that checks for that case.